# How to find deep difference in state of objects with Generics with Javers?

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, javers

I want to find deep difference in state of two objects of same type.

I tried using Javers. It fits exactly into my object state audit requirement. But the object I compare now has an attribute which has below signature where the Javers fails to work as it doesnt work with wildcards and nested generics. And the object I compare has class definition in a jar(A third party library) so I cant change the class definition.

Any workaround or any other similar framework in JAva is most welcome.

```
class A<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

I get below exception.

CLASS_EXTRACTION_ERROR : Javers bootstrap error - can't extract Class from type 'T'

Comment: JaVers won't help you, these generics are too complex

Comment: Can you please suggest any other framework in Java which does the same.. For now, I have converted both objects of different state to json and I use gson to compare &find the difference in state though its a lot of code to maintain and give transition to others.. Any suggestion on Java based framework is most welcome